# Existe alguna configuración adicional para exportar bases de datos de mysql a través phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Al tratar de exportar mi base de datos a través de phpMyAdmin en un servidor local estoy obteniendo un archivo de nombre sql sin extension, que contiene información de la pagina actual, como código HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang='es' dir='ltr'><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />
```

He intentado con varios navegadores y pasa lo mismo, incluso en un servidor en Internet y pasa exactamente lo mismo. Sera que la base de datos es muy grande? o se necesita alguna configuración adicional?

Comment: ummm y si pruebas con una tabla mas pequeña? Mira si te saca otro error. O instala el mysql workbench y la exportas por ahi. Saludos

Comment: cómo precisamente intentaste exportar esa base de datos?

Comment: @JorgeLondoño Si acabo de intentar con una sola tabla y se exporto correctamente, entonces posiblemente si sea un problema por el tamaño. Con Workbench intente pero me dio un error como de version de mySQL. De todas formas intentare mas por Workbench

Comment: otra opción es que lo exportes directamente desde la consola de comandos ya sea en windows o linux. Utilizando:                                            mysqldump -u [username] -p [database_name] > [dumpfilename.sql]           Ahi obtienes toda la BD, buscas el DDL y DML de la tabla y listo. Saludos

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo Pues ingrese primero (localhost/phpMyAdmin), seleccione mi base de datos, luego pestaña de exportar y luego en la opción rápida o personalizado. Cualquiera de los dos obtengo el mismo resultado